# how to reject or answer an incoming call witihn react native app with custom buttons(can i use react-native-call-keep)

Tags: android, react-native, phone-call

I am using react-native-call-detection package to save incoming call number (and send it on server later), I also want to reject/answer the incoming call based on the pressed button (based on server response later).
what package should I use to do it? I just found react-native-call-keep but all examples gave fake phone number to the functons and I don't know how to use its functions or how to get my call uuid.I just know there is reject/answer call function and I should call addEventListener functions before calling functions.

here is my current code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import RNCallKeep from 'react-native-callkeep';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import CallDetectorManager from 'react-native-call-detection';
import RNCallKeep from 'react-native-callkeep';

export default class MasterScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      featureOn: false,
      incoming: false,
      number: null,
    };


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.askPermission();
    this.startListenerTapped();
    this.setupCallKeep();
  }
   setupCallKeep() {
    const options = {
      android: {
        alertTitle: 'Permissions Required',
        alertDescription:
          'This application needs to access your phone calling accounts to make calls',
        cancelButton: 'Cancel',
        okButton: 'ok',
        imageName: 'ic_launcher',
        additionalPermissions: [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS],
      },
    };
  
    try {
      RNCallKeep.setup(options);
      RNCallKeep.setAvailable(true); // Only used for Android, see doc above.
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('initializeCallKeep error:', err.message);
    }
  }
  askPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const permissions = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CALL_LOG,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE,
      ]);
      console.log('Permissions are:', permissions);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  startListenerTapped = () => {
    this.setState({featureOn: true});
    this.callDetector = new CallDetectorManager(
      (event, phoneNumber) => {
        console.log(event);
        if (event === 'Disconnected') {
          this.setState({incoming: false, number: null});
        } else if (event === 'Incoming') {
          this.setState({incoming: true, number: phoneNumber});
        } else if (event === 'Offhook') {
          this.setState({incoming: true, number: phoneNumber});
        } else if (event === 'Missed') {
          this.setState({incoming: false, number: null});
        }
      },
      true,
      () => {},
      {
        title: 'Phone State Permission',
        message:
          'This app needs access to your phone state in order to react and/or to adapt to incoming calls.',
      },
    );
  };

  stopListenerTapped = () => {
    this.setState({featureOn: false});
    this.callDetector && this.callDetector.dispose();
  };


  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <Text>incoming call number: {this.state.number}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={/*what to do */}  style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}><Text>answer</Text></TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity  
            onPress={/*what to do */}  style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
              <Text>reject</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    backgroundColor: 'honeydew',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    padding: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  button: {},
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RNCallKeep.rejectCall`](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep#rejectcall). Like so

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPr ess={() => RNCallKeep.rejectCall(uuid)}
    st yle={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
>
    <Text>reject</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```